# Passbook (generic type) with 'locations' is not showing up on lock screen

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet

I can't configure a generic style pkpass to show up on lock screen.

I've read the apple docs, which explain that relevant date needs a location, but here I'm not supplying a date at all. I've used google maps to find my current Lat and Long, but can't get seem to get it to show on my lock screen.

```
  {
  "formatVersion" : 1,
  "passTypeIdentifier" : "pass.JetBoarding",
  "serialNumber" : "###############",
  "webServiceURL" : "###############",
  "authenticationToken" : "###############",
  "teamIdentifier" : "###############",
  "locations" : [
    {"latitude" : 47.627231, "longitude" : -122.326306, "relevantText" : "I am here" }
  ],
  "barcode" : {
    "message" : "TESTTESET",
    "format" : "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
    "messageEncoding" : "iso-8859-1"
  },
  "organizationName" : "TESTER",
  "description" : "TEST PASS",
  "foregroundColor" : "rgb(233, 198, 0)",
  "backgroundColor" : "rgb(45, 86, 147)",
  "labelColor" : "rgb(233, 198, 0)",
  "generic" : {
    "primaryFields" : [
      {
        "key" : "passenger",
        "label" : "PASSENGER",
        "value" : "Tommyboy "
      },
    ],
    "secondaryFields" : [
      {
        "key" : "membernumber",
        "label" : "MEMBER #",
        "value" : "0001"
      },
      {
        "key" : "designation",
        "label" : "DESIGNATION",
        "value" : "Founder"
      },      
      {
        "key" : "emoji",
        "label" : "EMOJI",
        "value" : ""
      }       
    ],     
    "auxiliaryFields" : [
      {
        "label" : "name",
        "key" : "NAME",
        "value" :  "Tom",
      },
      {
        "label" : "membersince",
        "key" : "MEMBER SINCE",
        "value" : "03/2017",
      }
    ],
    "backFields" : [
      {
        "key" : "welcomeback",
        "label" : "‍✈️ WELCOME ABOARD ‍✈️",
        "value" : "###############"
      },
      {
        "key" : "residence",
        "label" : " BOARDING PASS ",
        "value" : "###############"
      },
          {
        "key" : "contact",
        "label" : " CONTACT ",
        "value" : "###############",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide

"maxDistance": 500